# DateListPlot of divide-by-zero-errors

Tags: date-and-time

Here's the script:

```
dailyTestRatioChart = DateListPlot[data[All, {#Date, (#PositiveIncrease/#TotalTestResultsIncrease)} &],
    PlotRange -> All,
    PlotTheme-> "Detailed",
    PlotLabel-> "Daily Ratio Positive to All COVID-19 Tests, U.S.",
    ImageSize-> Large,
    PlotLabels->Column@{DateString[data[[1]][#Date &]],N[(data[[1]][#PositiveIncrease &]/data[[1]][#TotalTestResultsIncrease &])]}];
```

Problem is there are apparently instances where `#PositiveIncrease/#TotalTestResultsIncrease` causes a divide-by-zero error and the plot fails. Is there something I can apply to `#PositiveIncrease/#TotalTestResultsIncrease` to make it skip that data point if it causes an error?

Comment: Use `Select` or `DeleteCases` to remove the data points for which `#TotalTestResultsIncrease == 0` *before* plotting?

Comment: Note that you did not provide `data`, so we cannot be much more specific.